# Why does VCS based bug tracking software always use its own branch?

Tags: version-control, bug-tracking

I know this may seem like a silly and tiny issue, but I can't understand why they do this (take for example tic-git (https://github.com/schacon/ticgit) which appears to be quite popular). Surely it would be better to place the data in a folder and have it in every branch, so modifications to the bug database can persist across branches and merges, and bug fixes can be tied to the commit which resolved them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's the other approach, which [Bugs Everywhere](http://bugseverywhere.org) uses.  There's an old [LWN article](https://lwn.net/Articles/281849/) that does a survey of Distributed Bug Trackers as of a few years ago that may be of interest.

Comment: Interesting discussion, but still leaves me thinking I want it to be a directory rather than a branch :p. Bugs everywhere looks like what I want, so thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

By keeping bugs in a separate branch they avoid merging bugs.